# WPF Multiple triggers on the same property not working right

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers

I have 2 triggers on the same property of a checkbox, and it doesn't work quite right.

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>

    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
        <Setter TargetName="InnerText" Property="Text" Value="False" />
        <Trigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnUnCheck}"/>
        </Trigger.EnterActions>
    </Trigger>

    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="InnerText" Property="Text" Value="True" />
        <Trigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnCheck}"/>
        </Trigger.EnterActions>
    </Trigger>

</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

When I uncheck the CheckBox, the text is set, and the storyboard gets called just fine. But then when I check the CheckBox, the text gets set properly, but the storyboard isn't called. I can then uncheck the CheckBox, and that storyboard still works.

Then, if I swap the Trigger order, so `Value="True"` is the first one, only that storyboard works. In both cases the text is set just fine, and it confirms that both storyboards work. Its just the storyboard in the second Trigger doesn't get called in either case. Do I need to use a MultiTrigger...?

Edit: My storyboards were backward, so it's the first Trigger not calling the storyboard, not the second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No thanks to whoever downvoted my question, but I came up with a solution. Having separate Triggers didn't seem to work, so I edited my storyboards to contain the text setting, and put my `False` check into a `<Trigger.ExitActions>`,

```
<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnCheck}"/>
    </Trigger.EnterActions>
    <Trigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnUnCheck}"/>
    </Trigger.ExitActions>
</Trigger>
```

This also has the added benefit of not executing the `False` part as soon as the control is loaded.